Срез верхнего кода в WebStorm (дизайн)

Всем привет, столкнулся  такой проблемой при переустновке WebStorm, вижу верхний срез кода. До этого как-то убирал. Можете ли подсказать пункт в настройках, который убирает данный срез, и нормально показывает верхние строки кода.
На скрине видно, что после 55той строки, по срезу показывается 43, а должна 54...

Тут ответ по vscode, но может поможет и вам

Проблема решена. Параметр - sticky lines. Надеюсь, это тоже кого-то когда-то спасет.


Вам так и ответили в комментарии)
